# Unable to make code work in Jmeter´s Beanshell PreProcessor

Tags: javascript, java, jmeter, beanshell

I´m doing some web scraping using Apache Jmeter´s built-in WebDriver Sampler (with Javascript).

Before the test starts, I need to execute a certain amount of functions in order to build a specific user ID that matches some frontend validations.

In order to do so, I´m declaring and using those functions in each script block provided by the WebDriver sampler.

Since, those functions I need to run do only need to be executed once in the entire test plan (just as it starts), I was wondering if there was a way to use those functions in a BeanShell PreProcessor. Since my code works but was originally made on Javascript, I tried translating it to Java in order to be able to use them in Beanshell.

I keep getting the following error when I run the test:

```
ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: 
Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``//String DICTIONARY = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
String[] DICTIONARY = {"A"," . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Typed variable declaration : Typed variable declaration
```

My original javascript code is the following (this one works when used at WebDriver Sampler´s code block):

```
    var DICTIONARY = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
     
    function generateRandomString(length, dictionary) {
        var result = '';
        for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
            result += dictionary.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length));
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    function countChars(character, sentence){
        var count = 0
        for(var i=0; i<sentence.length; i++) {
               if (sentence[i] === character) count++
        }
        return count
    }
     
    function hasConsecutivesChars(sentence, length) {
            var charCounter = {}
        for (var i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
                var currentChar = sentence[i]
                if (countChars(currentChar, sentence) >= length) { 
            return true
                }
        }
        return false
    }
     
    function generateRandomStringWithoutConsecutivesChars(length, maxConsecutiveChars, dictionary, maxTries) {
        var isValidString = false
        var randomString = ''
        var tries = 0;
        while(!isValidString && tries <= maxTries) {
            randomString = generateRandomString(length, dictionary)
                var isValidString = !hasConsecutivesChars(randomString, maxConsecutiveChars)
                tries++;
         }
        return randomString 
    }
    
    function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // mínimo y máximo incluidos
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
    }
    
    var nombreUsuario = "SELENIUM_" + generateRandomStringWithoutConsecutivesChars(5, 3, DICTIONARY, 100) + randomIntFromInterval(1, 9);
```

And here is the same code translated into java and implemented in BeanShell PreProcessor (the one that´s failing):

```
String[] DICTIONARY = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

String generateRandomString(int length, String[] dictionary) {
    String result = "";
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        //result += dictionary.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length));
        result += dictionary[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)];
    }
    return result;
}

int countChars(String character, String sentence){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
           //if (sentence[i] == character){ 
           if (sentence.charAt(i) == character){ 
            count++;
           }
    }
    return count;
}
 
boolean hasConsecutivesChars(String sentence, int length) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String currentChar = sentence.charAt(i);
            if (countChars(currentChar, sentence) >= length) { 
        return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
 
String generateRandomStringWithoutConsecutivesChars(int length, int maxConsecutiveChars, String[] dictionary, int maxTries) {
    boolean isValidString = false;
    String randomString = "";
    int tries = 0;
    while(!isValidString && tries <= maxTries) {
        String randomString = generateRandomString(length, dictionary);
            boolean isValidString = !hasConsecutivesChars(randomString, maxConsecutiveChars);
            tries++;
     }
    return randomString; 
}

int randomIntFromInterval(int min, int max) { // mínimo y máximo incluidos
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

String id = generateRandomStringWithoutConsecutivesChars(5, 3, DICTIONARY, 100) + randomIntFromInterval(1, 9);

vars.put("id", id);

log.info(id);
```

**Side Note**: You´ll notice the translated code isn´t exactly the same as its original javascript counterpart. Those are some changes I made because I can´t access the string's length in Java, like i did in javascript.

Also, please excuse me for my rusty english, it´s not my mother tongue.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all are you aware or [RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) class which comes with JMeter?

If you still want to re-invent the wheel be informed that [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead) so consider switching to the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and the code like:

```
String[] DICTIONARY = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

String generateRandomString(int length, String[] dictionary) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        //result += dictionary.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length));
        result += dictionary[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26) as int];
    }
    return result;
}

int countChars(String character, String sentence) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        //if (sentence[i] == character){
        if (sentence.charAt(i) == character as char) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

boolean hasConsecutivesChars(String sentence, int length) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String currentChar = sentence.charAt(i);
        if (countChars(currentChar, sentence) >= length) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

String generateRandomStringWithoutConsecutivesChars(int length, int maxConsecutiveChars, String[] dictionary, int maxTries) {
    boolean isValidString = false;
    String randomString = "";
    int tries = 0;
    while (!isValidString && tries <= maxTries) {
        randomString = generateRandomString(length, dictionary);
        isValidString = !hasConsecutivesChars(randomString, maxConsecutiveChars);
        tries++;
    }
    return randomString;
}

int randomIntFromInterval(int min, int max) { // mínimo y máximo incluidos
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

String id = generateRandomStringWithoutConsecutivesChars(5, 3, DICTIONARY, 100) + randomIntFromInterval(1, 9);

vars.put("id", id);

log.info(id);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! i wasn´t aware of that. In this case, I´m not sure if  RandomStringUtils could serve the purpose of the above script since the id i need to build must not have three consecutive (and equal) characters. For example: AABCD is OK and AAABC is not. But i´ll take that into consideration. Thank you!